# Is possible to use one View like background to another View?

Tags: android, xml, view, android-linearlayout, android-progressbar

I have two custom circular `ProgressBar` and `TextView`. I need to add it in one `View`. Like `TextView` on `ProgressBar` on `ProgresBar`.
Hear is my XML -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/barTimer"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"/>
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progress_background" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question is about putting all of your views one above another (so in the one place)?

Of course it is possible, try to use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as a root layout. It will allow you to overlap one view by another depending on the order you added them to the code.

So probably your code should look smth like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="45">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/barTimer"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"/>
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progress_background"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```